# Creating an Address bar that doubles as a Google Search bar like in Chrome. VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, address-bar

I am trying to create a browser in Visual Studio 2013 using windows forms and the browser needs to have an Address bar that doubles as a Google Search bar like in Chrome. Here is my code for the Address bar, but I do not know what to put in after "If" and before "Then" in order to accomplish this. Any ideas?

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If                Then
            AxWebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
        Else
            AxWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`System.Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check that; I’d use `UriKind.Absolute`, though, because a lot of things are valid relative URIs.

```
Dim uri As Uri

If System.Uri.TryCreate(TextBox1.Text, UriKind.Absolute, uri) Then
    ' Navigate to it
Else
    ' Treat it as a search
End If
```

You could also make it a guess-free experience by requiring (or allowing) a prefix like `?`, which is easily checked with `s.StartsWith("?")` and removed with `s.Substring(1)`.

I just noticed the `Ax` prefix; if you’re using an ActiveX control,

- You can use [`System.Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the same first two parameters to just do a check instead of also creating a URI
- Don’t

Comment: Thank you for your help minitech. I appreciate it highly.